# void * cast for generic function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting, void

I'm trying to build a generic function as the one below

```
struct x {
    int l;
    char p;
};

struct y {
    int l;
    char p;
};

void test (void *t, int type)
{
   if (type)
     (struct y*)t;
   else
     (struct x*)t;

   t->l = 6;
   t->p = 'k';
}
```

Something like this, the variable t must have the same name for cast x* or y*. Do you have any idea if this is possible or have other suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
(struct y*)t;
```

Doesn't permanently change the type of `t`.  It takes the value of `t`, converts the type of that value from `void *` to `struct y *`, then discards that value since nothing is done with it.

After converting the pointer value, you can then dereference the resulting expression and assign to the appropriate member.

```
if (type)
  ((struct y*)t)->l = 1;
else
  ((struct x*)t)->l = 1;
```

Alternately, you can assign the value of `t` to a variable of the appropriate type and use that going forward:

```
if (type) {
    struct y *y1 = t;
    y1->l = 1;
    // do more with y1
} else {
    struct x *x1 = t;
    x1->l = 1;
    // do more with x1
}
```

If what you want is to work on two structs that have some common members, you need to create a separate struct with the common members and include that in each of the two structs.

```
struct z {
    int l;
    char p;
};

struct x {
    struct z z;
    int i;
};

struct y {
    struct z z;
    double j;
};

void test(struct z *t)
{
   t->l = 6;
   t->p = 'k';
}

int main()
{
    struct x x1;
    struct y y1;
    test((struct z*)&x1);
    test((struct z*)&y1);
}
```

The above cast is allowed because a pointer to a struct can be safely converted to a pointer to its first member.

Comment: Yeah i understand but i need to keep the type for the rest of the scope.

Comment: @Malak See my edit.  You can assign the pointer to one of the correct type and use that.

Comment: I see and I'm aware of this. But imagine two identical structs like the ones on my questions, inside a function which does the same thing for both but the types are different. I need to repeat the process for both?

Comment: @Malak C doesn't work that way.  Two structs with different names, even if they have identical members, are not compatibie with each other.  The closest you can come is having the two struts containing a third as the initial member containing any common fields.

Comment: Didn't understand. Look at my example i edited in order to be more clear.

Comment: @Malak My edit shows an example of the sub-struct with the common members.

Comment: Yeahh that was my optional approach... Only made this question in order to know if there is any kind of "permanent cast". Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Malak Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @Malak You should create a separate post for that.